# Symfony Doctrine Many to Many insert CollectionType

Tags: php, doctrine-orm, doctrine, symfony

I have a problem with my entities and controllers in Symfony. I would insert on my DB value in a many to many table generated.

Entity Requests with only many to many elements

```
class Requests {
  /**
 * @ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity="Tipi", inversedBy="requests")
 * @ORM\JoinTable(name="tipi_richieste")
 */
 private $tipi;


 public function __construct() {
    $this->tipi = new \Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection();
 }


 /**
 * Add tipi
 *
 * @param \AppBundle\Entity\Tipi $tipi
 *
 * @return Requests
 */
public function addTipi(\AppBundle\Entity\Tipi $tipi) {
    $this->tipi[] = $tipi;

    return $this;
}

/**
 * Remove tipi
 *
 * @param \AppBundle\Entity\Tipi $tipi
 */
public function removeTipi(\AppBundle\Entity\Tipi $tipi) {
    $this->tipi->removeElement($tipi);
}

/**
 * Get tipi
 *
 * @return \Doctrine\Common\Collections\Collection
 */
public function getTipi() {
    return $this->tipi;
}
}
```

Entity Tipi with only many to many elements

```
 class Tipi {
 /**
 * @ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity="Requests", mappedBy="tipi")
 */
 private $requests;


  /**
 * Constructor
 */
public function __construct() {
    $this->requests = new \Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection();
 }

      /**
 * Add request
 *
 * @param \AppBundle\Entity\Requests $request
 *
 * @return Tipi
 */
public function addRequest(\AppBundle\Entity\Requests $request)
{
    $this->requests[] = $request;

    return $this;
}

/**
 * Remove request
 *
 * @param \AppBundle\Entity\Requests $request
 */
public function removeRequest(\AppBundle\Entity\Requests $request)
{
    $this->requests->removeElement($request);
}

/**
 * Get requests
 *
 * @return \Doctrine\Common\Collections\Collection
 */
public function getRequests()
{
    return $this->requests;
}
 }
```

The Form type for insert is a CollectionType

```
->add('tipi', CollectionType::class, array(
                'entry_type' => TipiType::class,
                'allow_add' => true,
                'prototype' => true,
                'entry_options' => array(
                    'required' => true,
                    'label' => false,
                )
            ))
```

And TipiType is an EntityType

```
->add('tipi', EntityType::class, array(
                'label' => 'Tipo',
                'class' => 'AppBundle:Tipi',
                'attr' => array('class' => 'form-control'),
                'by_reference' => false,
                'query_builder' => function (EntityRepository $er) {
            return $er->createQueryBuilder('t');
        },
            ))
```

And in my controller I work in this way:

```
 public function indexAction(Request $request) {
    $requests = new Requests();
    $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
    $form = $this->createForm(RequestsType::class, $requests);
    $form->handleRequest($request);
    if ($form->isSubmitted() && $form->isValid()) {
        $requests->setCreateAt(new \DateTime('now'));
        $em->persist($requests);
        $em->flush();
        return $this->redirectToRoute('requests_edit', array('id' => $requests->getId()));
    }
    return $this->render('AppBundle:Requests:index.html.twig', array(
                'requests' => $requests,
                'form' => $form->createView(),
    ));
}
```

When I put die for return the value of `$form["tipi"]->getData()` I get an array collection : `Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection@000000005b52ae6b00000000731dd0b4`

But I get this error:

```
Expected value of type "Doctrine\Common\Collections\Collection|array" for association field "AppBundle\Entity\Requests#$tipi", got "AppBundle\Entity\Requests" instead.
```

Comment: @dragoste another problem -.-

Comment: I think it's issue with mapping. For sure, somewhere you've put `Doctrine\Common\Collections\Collection|array` when you shouldn't.

Comment: Yes i have this in my entities Requests and Tipi but i put this because i read that in doctrine documentation http://doctrine-orm.readthedocs.io/projects/doctrine-orm/en/latest/reference/association-mapping.html ...

Comment: I can't see anything like that under link you provide. In general it's incorrect. I can't help you more here without the code that the problem is about.

Comment: When i used Entity type in principal formtype it works, but now when i used collection type with another form type not.. I don't know.. I put the equals name in collection type and entity type, like the code @dragoste

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Symfony Doctrine Many to Many insert](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36885653/symfony-doctrine-many-to-many-insert)

Answer (score 1):

You need to do a foreach for this,
sample:

```
foreach $form->get("tipi")->getData() as $variableName) {
 //Here you just need the setter for each data from its own entity
->$manager
->setEntity(variableName)
// your entity tipi
}
```

then after that you flush it from you main transaction or entity, it will automatically insert all data from collection.